# NullPointerException java android

Tags: java, android

I'm new in java and android. Trying to make some app and got NullPointerException. Please see my code below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PoziomicaActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    TextView t1;
    TextView t2;
    TextView t3;
    TextView t4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_poziomica);

        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        t4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        SensorManager sensor = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor.registerListener(this,sensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),0,null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        t1.setText("event.values[0]="+event.values[0]+"\n" +
                "event.values[1]="+event.values[1]+"\n"+
                "event.values[2]="+event.values[2]+"\n");

        String kierunek="";
        if(event.values[0]==0){
            kierunek="Północ (N)";
        }else if(event.values[0]<90){
            kierunek="Północny-wschód (NE)";
        }else if(event.values[0]==90){
            kierunek="Wschód (E)";
        }else if(event.values[0]<180){
            kierunek="Południowy-wschód (SE)";
        }else if(event.values[0]==180){
            kierunek="Południe (S)";
        }else if(event.values[0]<270){
            kierunek="Południowy-zachód (SW)";          
        }else if(event.values[0]==270){
            kierunek="Zachód (W)";
        }else if(event.values[0]<360){
            kierunek="Północny-zachód (NW)";
        }                       
        t2.setText("idziesz na "+kierunek);

        String pochylenie_gd="";
        if(event.values[1]==0){
            pochylenie_gd="poziomo";
        }else if(event.values[1]>0){
            pochylenie_gd="góra niżej";
        }else{
            pochylenie_gd="dół niżej";
        }       
        t3.setText("Płaszczyzna góra-dół:  "+pochylenie_gd);

        String pochylenie_lp="";
        if(event.values[2]==0){
            pochylenie_lp="poziomo";
        }else if(event.values[2]>0){
            pochylenie_lp="lewa niżej";
        }else{
            pochylenie_lp="prawa niżej";
        }
        t4.setText("Płaszczyzna lewa-prawa:  "+pochylenie_lp);

        if((event.values[1]==0)&&(event.values[2]==0)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Idealny poziom!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Every time I got error:

```
java.lang.NullPointer.Exception at com.example.pomocnik.PoziomicaActivity.onSensorChenged (PoziomicaActivity.java:51).
```

Can someone tell me where is a problem?

Comment: Which line is line 51?

Comment: You know where the problem is (you just posted the error showing where it is). Investigate and see what is `null` there by setting a breakpoint and/or logs

Comment: else if(event.values[0]==90) this is line 51.

Comment: check if either event or event.values is null..

Comment: There's a site like Google, heard of it?